# Error when opening Allure test report "Upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: local reset"

Tags: c#, .net, networking, allure

I am using Allure to generate test report for my .NET project.

My test reports were previously loading on Chrome, when I used the command `allure open "allure-report"`

However today, I get the error  `"Upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: local reset"` when I access the server link

Why would this be?

Thank you